# Emulating Raspberry Pi with GUI on QEMU / Virtual box in Ubuntu with RAM > 256Mb

Tags: ubuntu, emulation, qemu, virtualization

I am searching for documentation on emulating Raspberry Pi with GUI on QEMU in Ubuntu with RAM size about 1Gb.

Most articles I found from google are either emulating 256Mb rpi with jessie or in the lite mode (they don't have any desktop tools) like below.

**1Gb but no mouse and no keyboard** : [Ubuntu 16.04, QEMU 2.9.0 -M raspi2, Raspbian 2016-05-27, vanilla kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45814913/1595504)

**256Mb** :[Raspbian "stretch" for Raspberry Pi 3 on QEMU](https://github.com/wimvanderbauwhede/limited-systems/wiki/Raspbian-%22stretch%22-for-Raspberry-Pi-3-on-QEMU)

Is there a way to emulate raspberry pi with 1Gb and Desktop ?

Thank you.